# How to simulate 5000 user login in 30min with MS accounts

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

We have a system to simulate 5000 users accessing the system concurrently in the 30-minute time span. It uses Microsoft online login accounts and authenticated users are redirected to the system.

**Note:** We have a limited number of user accounts for the testing. (20 user account)

User logins throughput  = 5000/(30*60) = 2.78 user logins/second

Considering the limited number of user account following is planned

1. Use 20 user accounts to simulate 3-5 logins/second for a period of 30 minutes with throughput controlling plugins
2. Simulate active user in the system with direct API calls

**Questions**

1. Is this a correct way to handle the required throughput with a limited number of user accounts?
2. What are the other options available

Answer (score 2):

1. In general the best practice is to have 1 to 1 mapping of JMeter thread (virtual user) to a real user. Depending on how does your application treat new logins it might not show the full picture, especially if some background activities are being triggered for each new login. Moreover, libraries, databases, operating systems, application servers, and other middleware tend to [cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)) requests results so 1 user making 5000 calls is not the same as 5000 users making 5000 calls.
2. Well-behaved load test needs to simulate real usage of the website (or application or service) as close as possible so if you're testing a website that communicates with the [backend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_end_and_back_end) using API - it's only a part of the traffic from the browser to the destination, in reality, things could be much more complicated like sending relevant [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers), downloading embedded resources (remember about [client-side caching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching) as well), executing [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) calls (when different API calls are being invoked by the same user in parallel) and so on. See [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) article for more details.

So recommendations are:

- generate another 4980 test users
- make sure that each virtual user's network footprint exactly matches the real browser (or other application which you're simulating) one